# jquery .click() problem - fires on third click

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to update a database using .ajax(). The idea is a 'user' can be enabled or disabled by setting a flag (bool) in the db from the admin account, the script 'activate.php' simply excecutes the db insert.

This does work but only after I have clicked on the trigger three times so obviously I am doing something wrong!

Code is as follows:

```
$('.changeStatus').click(function(){


    var currentStatus   = $('#activeDisp').attr('value');
    var activate        = "";
    var changeText      = "";
    var id              = $('#idDisp').attr('value');

    switch(currentStatus){
        case "0":
           var activate = 1;
           var changeText = "disable this user";
           $('#activeDisp').val(activate);
           break;
        case "1":
           var activate = 0;
           var changeText = "enable this user";
           $('#activeDisp').val(activate);
           break;
    }
    var dataString      = 'id='+ id +'&active='+ activate;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "activate.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(html) {
                $('.changeStatus').html("<a href='#' class='changeStatus'>"+ changeText +"</a>");
                //alert(html);
                }
               });
           return false;
    });
```

#activeDisp and #idDisp are text boxes which the values are inserted into by PHP when the page loads.

cheers

Comment: Where in the Javascript is your click handler added?  In `$(document).ready()` or elsewhere?

Comment: try this: $('.changeStatus').live('click', function(e) {

Comment: I'm using Google code so I've now got: 
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $('.changeStatus').live('click',function(){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

your code rewrited should be like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.changeStatus').live('click',function() {
        var currentStatus = $('#activeDisp').val();
        var activate = (currentStatus == 1) ? 0: 1;
        var changeText = (currentStatus == 1) ? "disable this user": "enable this user";
        var id = $('#idDisp').val();
        $('#activeDisp').val(activate);
        var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&active=' + activate;    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "activate.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.changeStatus').text(changeText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** if you set the `currentStatus` to return a vulue equal to the `active` one you can have less code.

Comment: Cheers - I just gave that a go but it doesn't seem to have solved the problem, is there anything else in the code that would need to be altered for .live() to function? After 3 clicks on "<a href='#' class='changeStatus'>message</a>" it works totally as intended...

Comment: i have rewrited your code entirely. take a look and let me know.